# Eclipse code assistance in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for developing Java applications, and my problem is with Code Assistance.   How do I get the code assist for a declaration to include the modifiers?  For example when I type `stat..` I want Eclipse to include `static`.  In other contexts, it should offer access modifiers; e.g. `public` and `private`.

Comment: So when you write `publ` and press ctrl+space, what happens? For me it suggests appropriate completions.

Comment: Is it not quicker just to type the keyword, rather than rely upon the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a member variable take pointer to start of the data type then press ctrl+space, eclipse should give you the default proposals like shown below:

[image]

If you face any issue or want to tweak the content assist settings click on

Windows > Preference > Java > Editor > Content Assist

[image]